# Why does a time out occur evertime I query my Cassandra database?

Tags: php, cassandra

Underneath is our table description:

```
、CREATE KEYSPACE statistics
WITH replication = {
 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
 'replication_factor' : 2
};



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS statistics;

CREATE TABLE statistics (
 source text,
 timespan text,
 id text,
 title text,
 thumbnail text,
 url text,
 text text,
 created_at timestamp,
 category text,
 category2 text,
 genre text,
 author text,
 reads int,
 likes int,
 comments int,
 shares int,
 speed int,
 PRIMARY KEY (source, timespan, id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timespan DESC) AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"ALL"}';
```

created the index by Stratio’s Cassandra Lucene Index(https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index)

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statistics_index ON statistics (text)
USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index'
WITH OPTIONS = {
 'refresh_seconds' : '10',
    'schema' : '{
        fields : {
            title    : {type : "text", analyzer : "english"},
   category : {type:"string"},
   category2 : {type:"string"},
   genre : {type:"string"},
   speed  : {type : "integer",sorted : true}
        }
    }'
};
```

When the front end display queries, using php, the cassandra database this error message occurs:

```
{"message":"Unavailable exception. Error data: array (\n  'consistency' => 2573153,\n  'node' => 1852731252,\n  'replica' => 543253352,\n)","data":{"source":"weibohao","timespan":"1","category":"","genre":"","sort":"speed","sql":"SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE source = 'weibohao' AND timespan = '1' AND text = '{ sort: {fields: [{field: \"speed\", reverse: true}]}}' limit 100"}}
```

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Unavailable exception" is different from a timeout. It means that enough of the replicas necessary to satisfy your desired consistency level were not available.

You have a replication factor of two so if you do anything above a consistency level of ONE it will require both replicas to be up at the time of the query or you will get this message.

Comment: Why are there not enough replicas and how can I check the available replicas?